# Yarn error on docker container built from php:7.4-fpm dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, yarnpkg

I'm trying to install yarn into container built from a dockerfile :

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm
...
// install node
RUN echo "deb https://deb.nodesource.com/node_6.x jessie main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodejs.list && \
wget -nv -O -  https://deb.nodesource.com/gpgkey/nodesource.gpg.key | apt-key add - && \
echo "deb-src https://deb.nodesource.com/node_6.x jessie main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodejs.list && \
apt-get update && \
apt-get install -y --force-yes nodejs && \
rm -f /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodejs.list
// install yarn 
RUN curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | APT_KEY_DONT_WARN_ON_DANGEROUS_USAGE=DontWarn apt-key add - && \
echo "deb http://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list && \
apt-get update && \
apt-get install --no-install-recommends yarn
```

Then, inside the container :

```
yarn --version
0.32+git
```

and i got errors when i try to run yarn install

[image]

[image]

Comment: yarn install: installs all the dependencies defined in a package.json file.? do you have package.json file in /home/wwwroot ?

Comment: yes, it's an error about yarn installation, even if i don't have a package.json, i'm not supposed to got those errors

Comment: Try to use `yarn` command to install all the dependencies defined in a package.json file

Comment: i updated my question, i added a scrennshot showing the result of yarn install

Answer (score 1):

for yarn, try this :

```
RUN apt-get install -y gnupg

RUN curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | APT_KEY_DONT_WARN_ON_DANGEROUS_USAGE=DontWarn apt-key add - && \
echo "deb http://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list && \
apt-get update && \
apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends yarn
```

for node i suggest this :

```
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x -o nodesource_setup.sh
RUN bash nodesource_setup.sh
RUN apt-get install nodejs
RUN rm nodesource_setup.sh
```